# how to take common factors out from css where it is separated by comma (,)

Tags: css, sass, less

I want to reduce this code. I do not want to type #panelbar everytime. 
for example:

```
#panelbar .col-md-1,
#panelbar .col-md-2,
#panelbar .col-md-3,
#panelbar .col-md-4,
#panelbar .col-md-5
{
----------------------
properties----------
}
```

is there is a way to reduce this code???

Comment: nope. CSS isn't nestable. It should have been from the get-go. but the "intelligent" people on the design committee didn't allow for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What about this ?** (elements with class name begins with... **col-md-**)

```css
#panelbar [class^="col-md-"] {
   //properties
}
```

**Or SASS/LESS style :**

```css
#panelbar {
    [class^="col-md-"] {
        //properties
    }
}
```

If your element using **multiple classes**, you need some fallback like :

```css
#panelbar [class^="col-md-"],
#panelbar [class*=" col-md-"] {
   //properties
}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/v8uuL/

**Compatibility table :** http://caniuse.com/css-sel2

*But I recommend to do as @MarkM says (more faster and reusable)*

Comment: You can add `<!-- language: lang-css -->` to the start of the code blocks to specify CSS syntax colouring.

Answer (score 5):

You can leverage CSS pre-processors like LESS and SASS. If you use LESS, your syntax would be

```
#panelbar {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5
  {
    //properties...
  }
}
```

See http://lesscss.org/

Comment: (Assuming Less) Personally I would even go with something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/097436bd9a71e1660f99#file-25069346-less) :).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a preprocessor, you might consider just adding an additional class to these elements:

`<div id="#panelbar">
    <div class="col-md-1 anotherClass"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 anotherClass"></div>
</div>`

Then you can write one selector:
`#panelbar .anotherClass {}`

This captures what's really going on in a more idiomatic way.

Alternatively, you can use the child selector if it works with your document structure:
`#panelbar > div {}`

Answer (score 1):

Without using a CSS generator, no, there is no way to reduce/simplify that and retain the same  ID/class structure.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called attribute selector. An example, using a hypothetical html structure, with your css class names :

```
<div id="panelbar">
   <div class="col-md-1"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

You would define your CSS like so:

```
 #panelbar [class*='col-md-']{
   ----------------------
   properties----------
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably do that with a CSS preprocessor. SASS and Less are the most popular.

- http://sass-lang.com/
- http://lesscss.org/

Check out this specifically in SASS http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3

Now, how to install the preprocessor is mainly dependent on the framework you use, although you can tell it to precompile stuff manually.